# Add Spring security Java Config to Spring config

Tags: spring, spring-security

i'm working on a spring application lately, and i wanted to add spring security to my app.

I had a simple page containing a login form working like a charm, but when i wanted to add the spring security configuration to the app i get an error.

Here's the code of my SecurityConfig file :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

/*@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}*/

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
          .authorizeRequests()
            /*.antMatchers("/infermier*//**").hasRole("INFERMIER")
            .antMatchers("/docteur*//**").hasRole("DOCTEUR")
            .antMatchers("/user*//**").hasRole("USER")*/
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .permitAll();
}

}
```

And here's the log :

```
Error invoking ServletContainerInitializer org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1183)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1728)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
    at configuration.WebInitializer.getRootConfigClasses(WebInitializer.java:12)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.context.AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.registerContextLoaderListener(AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.context.AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.onStartup(AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.java:47)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.onStartup(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5997)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5895)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
  Startup of context /servicemed failed due to previous errors]]

[2014-08-13T12:57:16.429+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-CORE-00175] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=37 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1407931036429] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Manager has not yet been started
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:6099)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5916)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5920)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
```

PS: I did added it to the MVCInitializer :

```
@Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class,SecurityConfig.class};
    }
```

Comment: The class was present at the compile time but couldn't be found at runtime. You might want to check your runtime configuration to pinpoint the real cause.

Comment: well to be honest i don't know how to do that, i'm using Intellij, can you give me hint ;)

Comment: Well what I would do is to go to the Maven Projects window and run `clean`, `install` lifecycles and then try running the project again.

Comment: OMG that worked, oh a million thanks man, that took me about 3 days now hihihi.Oh btw, the solution you gave me, what did just happened ? xD How about you add it as a solution, with some more explanation if you don't mind :D

Comment: probably `target` folder got messed up so cleaning it, and then putting everything defined in your pom file together again fixed the mess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@idursun gave me a solution and a nice explanation, there was nothing wrong with the configuration i made (it actually worked afterwards), and the problem was that the **target**
folder got messed up, so i cleaned it using the maven projects tool and installed everything all over again (using the same tool), and voila, everything is good

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have [spring-security-config](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config) in your classpath. Obviously it is missing at the runtime.

In such case running `mvn clean install` prior to running your application can fix the problem.

Comment: i use maven, and spring-security-config is already out there , that's how it's done no ?

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ... That means a class of name XYZ has not been found on your classpath. Add [spring-security-config.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security) to your classpath.

Comment: i already have the spring-security-config dependency in pom.xml (i'm using maven) and i double checked the external librairies and found this class in that jar

Comment: If you are sure all necessary spring security jars are in WEB-INF lib of your war, it could be because there are other versions of spring security in classpath.

Comment: i have only the 3.2.4.REALEASE version , i checked it

Answer (score 0):

It was a wrong maven project packaging type, in my case:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

instead of

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```